# How to replace 'if statement' with rx-java for avoiding callback hell?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to replace my code with rx-java. (It is very small code.)

It is finished and it works.

But I want to know...

1. Is it a good Rx style?
2. If not good, please indicate bad point

Below is my code that is api handling.

before

```
Random r = new Random();
boolean apiResult = r.nextBoolean(); // it represents api result. ex. {"result": true} or {"result": false}

if (apiResult == true) {
    // do something

    System.out.println("result:" + "success");
} else {
    // do something

    System.out.println("result:" + "failure");
}
```

after

```
Random r = new Random();
Observable<Boolean> apiResultStream = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
        // emit true or false
         subscriber.onNext(r.nextBoolean());
    }
}).cache(1);


// I used filter for split. Is it Rx style?
// success if true emitted.
Observable<Boolean> successStream = apiResultStream
        .filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean == true); // here

// failure if false emitted.
Observable<Boolean> failureStream = apiResultStream
        .filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean == false); // here


// success flow
successStream
        .flatMap(aBoolean -> Observable.just("success"))
        // and do something
        .subscribe(aString -> System.out.println("result:" + aString));

// failure flow
failureStream
        .flatMap(aBoolean -> Observable.just("failure"))
        // and do something.
        // I want to keep subscriber.
        .subscribe(aString -> System.out.println("result:" + aString));
```

**EDIT**

I almost replaced. [thanks for good comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290163/how-to-replace-if-statement-in-rx-java/28323856#28323856)
(but I have a few non-replaced code. It have many callback and if statement.)

I want to avoid 'callback hell'.

The key is different result type between 'callSuccessApi' and 'callFailureApi'

before rx

```
// callback hell!
callApi(new Callback<Result>(){
    @Override
    public void success(Result result) {
        if (result.Response == true) {
            callSuccessApi(new Callback<ResultSuccess>(){
                @Override
                public void success(ResultSuccess result) {
                    // and more callbacks...
                }
            }
        } else { // result.Response == false
            callFailureApi(new Callback<ResultFailure>(){
                @Override
                public void success(ResultFailure result) {
                    // and more callbacks...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after with rx(avoid callback hell! Is it a good Rx style?)

```
// change 1st api to observable.(I changed other api to observable)
Observable<Result> apiResultStream = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
        callApi(new Callback<Result>(){
            @Override
            public void success(Result result) {
                subscriber.onNext(result);
            }
        });
    }
}).cache(1); // ensure same Observable<Result> for success and failure.


// I used filter for split. Is it Rx style?
// success if result.response == true.
Observable<ResultSuccess> successStream = apiResultStream
        .filter(result -> result.response == true); // here

// failure if result.response == false.
Observable<ResultFailure> failureStream = apiResultStream
        .filter(result -> result.response == false); // here


// success flow. callSuccessApi return Observable<ResultSuccess>
successStream
        .flatMap(result -> callSuccessApi(result))
        // and more api call with flatMap...
        .subscribe(resultSuccessN -> System.out.println("result:" + resultSuccessN.toString()));

// failure flow. callFailureApi return Observable<ResultFailure>
failureStream
.flatMap(resultFailure -> callFailureApi(result))
        // and more api call with flatMap...
        .subscribe(resultFailureN -> System.out.println("result:" + resultFailureN.toString()));
```

sorry for my poor English and long question.

**Updated My Code**

I got 2 important information in this question.(thank you @Tomáš Dvořák, @Will

1. whether it is a good way to go depends on the particular situation.
2. There's nothing wrong with using an if statement within an map / flatmap / subscribe.

updated code

```
Observable<Result> apiResultStream = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            callApi(new Callback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result result) {
                    subscriber.onNext(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // In this case,   I used 'if' for simply and cleanly.
    apiResultStream
            .subscribe(result -> {
                if (result.response == true) {
                    callSuccessApi(); // this line looks like 'callback'. but I used this for simply and cleanly.
                } else {
                    callFailureApi();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Concrete usage of the operators depends on the situation. Go with the simplest solution, in this case `apiResultStream.subscribe(aBoolean -> if (aBoolean) {doSomething} else {doSomethingElse}`. With this approach, you don't even need to cache it (which was odd anyway). It is hard to recommend more when we don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks good advice. I updated question to 'avoid callback hell'.

Comment: Even after your update, the problem you have presented is that you want to perform one of the two side-effecting actions depending on the value of the boolean observable. My simple solution still applies and solves your example simply and cleanly. If in fact you have a different problem to solve, please post it. Btw, of course you can use `filter` to split the flow, but, again, whether it is a good way to go depends on the particular situation.

Comment: I understood why your solution is good. I applied it to my code. The code became a simple and clean. situation is important! thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are loads of ways of doing this and it really depends on your use case. In general I wouldn't want to split into 2 streams, as that makes your code less readable. Also, I'm not sure what benefit you get from the flatMap call. There's nothing wrong with doing if stuff within a map call.

Here are a few options:

1 - For adding logging (a bit like your print lines), I use `doOnEach()`

```
apiResultStream
  .doOnEach(next -> {
    if (next) logger.info("Logging true " + next);
    else  logger.info(Logging false " + next);
  })
  .subscribe(....
```

2 - The work you're doing is part of your stream, and you're going to want to do more work on the stream later - use `map`

```
apiResultStream
  .map(next -> {
        if (next) doSomeCallWithNextWhenTrue(next);
        else doSomeCallwithNextWhenFalse(next);
      })
  .subscribe(...
```

3 - If this is work you want to do at the end of the pipeline - IE after all transformational or other stream like work has completed, then do it in the subscribe call.

```
apiResultStream
  .subscribe(next -> {
            if (next) doSomeCallWithNextWhenTrue(next);
            else doSomeCallwithNextWhenFalse(next);
          });
```

The problem is - with such a simple use case, it's difficult to suggest the best option, but I appreciate that in learning Rx, working out how to do conditional statements can seem confusing. In general, I just use `map` or `flatMap` when I'm calling another method that returns an `Observable` and do my logic in there.

**Update**

Still not sure why you're splitting your streams. Unless you start getting clever with different threads, the first subscribe call is going to block the second which is probably not what you want. Also, if you don't call subscribe more than once, then  you don't need the `cache()` call.

There's nothing wrong with using an `if statement` within an `map` / `flatmap` / `subscribe`. Especially if it makes your code more readable.

I would do the following:

```
apiResultStream
  .flatMap(result -> {
    if (result.response == true) {
      return callSuccessApi(result)
    }
    else {
      return callFailureApi(result)
  })
  //Do any more calls you need
  .subscribe(...
```

So much cleaner.

I'm a bit confused by your `System.out.println` calls in subscribe. Is this there for debug or logging purposes? If so, just do that within the above flatMap in the if statement.

Hope this helps,

Will

Comment: thanks good comment. I applied this comment to my code. but I couldn't replace 'callback hell'. so I updated my question.

Comment: sorry for confuse. println represented 'doSomething'. My code have a different return type betwen callSuccessApi and callFailureApi. In this case, can I apply this solution?

Comment: @kyanro Yes you can have different return types. If you're using Java8 lambdas then the return type is inferred, otherwise you'll need to use `Observable<?>`. If the `callSuccesAPI` call is intended as terminating operation - IE it's the end of the stream flow, then it makes perfect sense to do it in the subscribe call.

Comment: I understood. if I don't need 'return type' in 'onNext', it is perfect! (IE, 'end notifycation'). (or in some case, I can use 'instanceof' in 'onNext' for 'return type'). **a good way to go depends on the particular situation!**.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the if/else and to not break the chain™, I like to use publish and merge to split and re-merge the stream:

```
apiResultStream
  .publish(results -> 
    Observable.merge(
        results.filter(result -> result.response == true)
               .flatmap(result -> callSuccessApiObservable()),
        results.filter(result -> result.response == false)
               .flatmap(result -> callFailureApiObservable())
    )
  )
  .subscribe(...
```